# Объясните как добавлять строку в динамический массив при помощи malloc, realloc!

Tags: c, строки, динамические-массивы

Тема: Обработка многомерных динамических массивов. Переделать задание с применением динамических массивов.
Для полученного массива реализовать добавление строки элементов в заданной позиции (значение
позиции и элементов строки вводятся с клавиатуры).
Здраствуйте, дали задание, но как делать комментариев не дали. В методичке также указаны методы malloc,realloc,calloc. Но как их связать с моим двумерным динамическим массивом понять не могу. Если объясните или дадите наводку, то буду признателен.
Мой полученный код:

```
      int M;
      scanf("%d",&M);
      int N;
      scanf("%d",&N);
      float **A = (float*)malloc(M * sizeof(float*));
      for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      A[i] = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
      }
      float a = 10.00;
       float b = -10.00;
      for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            A[i][j] = (float)rand()*(b - a)/RAND_MAX + a;
            printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            printf("%.3f",A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
      }

      }

       printf("Where u want add line?");
       printf("Write position from 0 to %d\n",M);
       int pos;
      scanf("%d",&pos);
      int nac = M;
       ++M;
       printf("%d\n",nac);
       A = realloc(A,M * sizeof(float*));
      for(int i = M - 1; i != position; i--){

      }
```

Comment: *я первоначально создаю сам массив, а потом мне нужно добавить в него строку.

Comment: Нужен ваш код .

Comment: Сначала, вызвав malloc, получаете память для массива указателей на строки матрицы, скажем, `a`. Затем в цикле по, допустим, `i` вызывате malloc, получая память под каждую строку и запоминаете этот указатель в `a[i]`. Это часть 1, начало. Затем вызываете realloc для, `a`, увеличивая этот массив на один элемент. Начиная с конца, до позиции, например, `pos` копируете указатели на строки, таким образом освобождаете элемент `a[pos]` под новую строку. Вызываете malloc и записываете указатель в `a[pos]`. Вот, в общих чертах, и все комментарии, которые могут вам пригодиться

Comment: Я разобрался с первой частью и с realloc по увеличению, но немного не понимаю куда  указатели на строки, код я добавил..

Comment: @ЧастоПросящийОПомощи, смотрите, вы будете добавлять новую строку в `A[position]`. Соответственно, все указатели на строки с индексом строки больше чем position надо сдвинуть вправо.  Сначала копируете последнюю строку на новое место, потом предпоследнюю на место последней и т.д. Т.е. сам цикл перебора индексов вы написали правильно (!).Осталось дописать `A[i] = A[i - 1]; в нем. (Почему мы идем от хвоста к началу, понятно?)

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, я теперь разобрался!